# Laravel: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory

Tags: laravel, apache

Laravel version: 8.75

```
composer update

In CaBundle.php line 133:

  tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

Both have the same result:

```
composer update
composer install
```

---

Now I found that the problem is caused by php.ini sys_temp_dir

default

```
;sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

Last time I change to this, but I forgot why I did this.

```
sys_temp_dir = "C:\windows\Temp"
```

This also cause problem

```
sys_temp_dir = "tmp"
```

Should we set sys_temp_dir in php.ini ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this problem. It is due to the access right to the folder C:\Windows\Temp. Please apply one of the following two solutions:

1. You can launch your command in a terminal opened in administrator
   mode [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3HLs.png)
2. Change the permissions on the windows temporary folder
   C:\Windows\Temp for all PC users

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T9B0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'data');
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($tmp, ZipArchive::CREATE);//OVERWRITE    //CREATE
$zip->addFromString('aaa.txt', 'data');//zip on the fly 
$zip->close();
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.zip"');

ob_clean();
flush();

if (file_exists($tmp))
    readfile($tmp);
else
    echo 'No file';
```